# Is there a way to inject userscript into mobile webpage and keep it after reloading?

Tags: javascript, android, userscripts

I created an userscript to help me farm on a browser game. I have been running it in the background, on my pc, and everything was going on great, but.

I want to be able to run it on my old phone so that I won't have to keep my pc open all the time (I wanna run this 24/7). I have tried using tampermoney for android, but I couldn't get it to work at all, so I started using DevTools and injecting the javascript code into the page manually trough console with a Snippet.

The problem is that the game session expires after a while, and I couldn't find a method to log back in without refreshing the page, but once I do that, the script is lost and I have to reconnect my phone to my pc and inject it using DevTools.

Is there any way I could keep the Snippet after refreshing, inject the userscript without DevTools or is there any other solution you can think of?

Answer (score 1):

[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) was available for older Firefox versions on Android. I think support stopped around August 2020. Until then it seemed to work fine to me.
I don't know if it is still possible to install Greasemonkey if you install an old Firefox version on Android but it's worth a try.

Another solution would be to create your own Android app. In an Android app you can use `WebView` to display a website and inject javascript with [evaluateJavascript(codestring, callback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))

Comment: Or simple proxy (with python or whatever )  which will inject custom script into web page on reload